# How can i check website content plagiarism by posting a particular Url in my Asp.net MVC Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to implement a method for checking plagiarism in website content.

When I submit a particular URL I need to get the places where the web content is used or manipulated.

Is there any API to do that?

Comment: I don't think an API for .NET exists. And implementing an plagiarism checker yourself is pretty hard. You could use plagiarism sites like http://www.copyscape.com/ . The alternative is to make requests to sites like this with the URL from code and interpret the results in your code. If you search enough you may find sites that provide answer for such request in a free manner, easily done from code.

Comment: Hi @CoralDoe is there any site which provides plagiarism checking freely?

Comment: There is http://plagiarism-detect.com/ or http://www.plagiarismchecker.com/url/ but you can check online (the famous google search) in order to find what suits you best.

Comment: I think http://www.copyscape.com/ is far better

Comment: It is better, but what will you do when you will exceed your monthly limit? The service will not be free anymore.

Comment: @CoralDoe but by using plagiarismchecker.com/url sometimes returning error

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Copyleaks](https://copyleaks.com) API to check for plagiarism, it fully supports C# and .Net applications. The API is based on HTTP RESTful architecture. It's pretty simple to integrate and work with. 
Create a new visual studio project and install Copyleaks API [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CopyleaksAPI/).

To scan your content for plagiarism simply call the function 'scan' with your credentials. Here is a sample code (from their open source [GitHub SDK](https://github.com/Copyleaks/API)):

```
public void Scan(string username, string apiKey, string url)
{
    // Login to Copyleaks server.
    Console.Write("User login... ");
    LoginToken token = UsersAuthentication.Login(username, apiKey);
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tSuccess!");

    // Create a new process on server.
    Console.Write("Submiting new request... ");
    Detector detector = new Detector(token);
    ScannerProcess process = detector.CreateProcess(url);
    Console.WriteLine("\tSuccess!");

    // Waiting to process to be finished.
    Console.Write("Waiting for completion... ");
    while (!process.IsCompleted())
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("\tSuccess!");

    // Getting results.
    Console.Write("Getting results... ");
    var results = process.GetResults();
    if (results.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tNo results.");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Result {0}:", i + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", results[i].Domain);
            Console.WriteLine("Url: {0}", results[i].URL);
            Console.WriteLine("Precents: {0}", results[i].Precents);
            Console.WriteLine("CopiedWords: {0}", results[i].NumberOfCopiedWords);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, read their full [tutorial](https://api.copyleaks.com/Guides/HowToUse).

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that such method doesn't exist.